# Prove this diophantine equation $2^a-3^b=5~，a,b\in N^{+} $ has no postive integers solution

Tags: diophantine-equations

show that  the diophantine equation 
$$2^a-3^b=5~~~~,a>5,b>3，a,b\in N^{+}
$$  has no postive integers solution

maybe is old problem,But I try somedays,can't solve it by now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Please see this](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183498786) paper of Herschfeld (pages 232 and 233) for a proof. The machinery used is elementary.  I think the result was first proved by Pillai.